# Guardar en una variable el valor de una columna usando un WHILE

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de guardar un valor en una variable.

Creo la tabla e inserto registros.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (IDSOL INT not null PRIMARY KEY ,USUARIO VARCHAR(50) ,LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,FirstName varchar(255),Age int, )

INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(1,'ADMIN','RODRIGUEZ','LOPEZ',20)
INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(2,'ADMIN','YAÑEZ','CARROL',20)
INSERT INTO #TEMP 
VALUES(3,'ADMIN','MONS','JAFET',20)
```

Despues necesito guadrar en una variable la columna `IDSOL` por lo cual estoy utilizando un `WHILE` esto es lo que tengo.

```
DECLARE @I INT
DECLARE @J INT
DECLARE @VALOR_IDSOL 

SET @I =  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP WHERE USUARIO = 'ADMIN')
SET @J = 1

WHILE @I >= @J
BEGIN   

    SET @VALOR_IDSOL = (SELECT IDSOL FROM #TEMP WHERE USUARIO = 'ADMIN')

    SET @J = @J + 1

END
```

Obtengo la cantidad de registros de la consulta y despues paso la misma cantidad de registros por el `WHILE` quiero obtener el valor `IDSOL` del primer registro y en la siguiente vuelta el segundo registro y en la tercera vuelta lo mismo y de esa manera hasta que se termine, alguien me pude dar alguna idea.

Comment: Cual es el problema? que @VALOR_IDSOL  se pisa con cada bucle? o vos queres que el sp te devuelva por cada vuelta un valor y luego siga con el bucle?. si es esto ultimo no seria así, deberías guardar los resultados en una tabla temporal y al terminar el proceso devolver los registros de la tabla

Comment: Necesito tener el valor por cada vuelta, ya que lo obtenga voy hacer otro procedimiento que no esta en el codigo que muestro.

Comment: y por cada valor que obtenes, necesitas hacer un proceso con el otro SP que no esta en el codigo que mostras?

Comment: es dentro del mismo SP y el otro proceso es un `INSERT`

Comment: Completa el código asi queda mas claro

Comment: Solo necesito obtener por cada vuelta el valor del primer registro, luego el segundo y asi sucesivamente no es relevante el demas codigo por eso no lo muetro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entendi estas buscando iterar sobre cada registro en la tabla #temp y acceder a cada id dentro de la tabla para hacer lo que requieras con ese id, lo cual lo puedes lograr con un cursor de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @IDSOL_REGISTRO INT

DECLARE CUR CURSOR FOR
SELECT IDSOL FROM #TEMP
OPEN CUR
FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @IDSOL_REGISTRO
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
    --@IDSOL_REGISTRO CONTIENE EL VALOR DEL REGISTRO ACTUAL EL CUAL PUEDES USAR EN LO QUE NECESITES
    --AQUI VA LO QUE NECESITES HACER CON EL IDSOL DEL REGISTRO
    FETCH NEXT FROM CUR INTO @IDSOL_REGISTRO
  END
CLOSE CUR
DEALLOCATE CUR
```

Answer (score 0):

Segun lo que se hablo en los comentarios, por cada valor obtenido se ejecuta otro sp al que se le pasa este valor

```
  DECLARE @I INT
    DECLARE @J INT
    DECLARE @VALOR_IDSOL 

    SET @I =  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TEMP WHERE USUARIO = 'ADMIN')
    SET @J = 1

    WHILE @I >= @J
    BEGIN   

        SET @VALOR_IDSOL = (SELECT IDSOL FROM #TEMP WHERE USUARIO = 'ADMIN')

        /*Ejecuta el otro sp pasando el valor*/
        Exec sp_quenoestaenelcodigo(@VALOR_IDSOL)
         SET @J = @J + 1

    END
```